# Quandl EIA natural gas data

Tags: python-3.x, quandl

I am using QUANDL as a data source, and was able to get obtain the following data set into Python: 
I was able to get the following data set into Python:

`data=quandl.get("EIA/STEO_NGPRPUS_M")`

(https://www.quandl.com/data/EIA/STEO_NGPRPUS_M).

I'm having a lot of trouble getting the Date and Value as two separate columns. This is a dataframe, but the columns seem to combined into one string or something. Has anyone dealt with this or a similar data set before?
Chet

[Here's a screenshot of the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biMdw.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a sample of the dataframe?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh - Thanks man.....to post a sample, I can put it into a csv file...but then I find that the date and columns are separate values, as intended. In Python itself, it appears as one combined row: e.g. [68]


test.iloc[0]...
Value    52.167201
Name: 1990-01-31 00:00:00, dtype: float64 . It will be easiest if you extract it directly from Quandl, using the code I provided above. Quandl can be installed via conda: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/quandl . Will this work?

Comment: Looks like the solution is to use "rest_index". I tried the following on the extracted data frame:

    Data.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True)
    Data.tail()

Now, the dataframe looks "normal", with separate columns for "Date" and "Value. There's a bit of a learning curve, but it pays to keep researching! BTW - I can't post as "answer your own question"...will try to fix that.